# column "sn" named in key does not exist LINE 6: PRIMARY KEY (SN, PN, JN)

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have created 3 tables with the following queries:

S table:

```
CREATE TABLE S (
    SN INT,
    SNAME CHAR(10),
    RATING FLOAT,
    CITY CHAR(10),
    PRIMARY KEY (SN)
)
```

J table:

```
CREATE TABLE J (
    JN INT,
    JNAME CHAR(10),
    CITY CHAR(10),
    PRIMARY KEY (JN)
)
```

P table:

```
CREATE TABLE P (
    PN INT,
    PNAME CHAR(10),
    COLOR CHAR(10),
    CITY CHAR(10),
    WEIGHT FLOAT,
    PRIMARY KEY (PN)
)
```

and they successfully created without any errors.

The problem is that when I try to run the following query I face with a weird error:

```
 CREATE TABLE SPJ (
    QTY INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (SN) REFERENCES S(SN),
    FOREIGN KEY (PN) REFERENCES P(PN),
    FOREIGN KEY (JN) REFERENCES J(JN),
    PRIMARY KEY (SN, PN, JN)
)
```

> ERROR: column "sn" named in key does not exist LINE 6:  PRIMARY KEY (SN, PN, JN)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create the columns AND the foreign keys.  They foreign keys don't create the columns, they're actually just Constraints.

```
CREATE TABLE SPJ (
    QTY INT,
    SN  INT,
    PN  INT,
    JN  INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (SN) REFERENCES S(SN),
    FOREIGN KEY (PN) REFERENCES P(PN),
    FOREIGN KEY (JN) REFERENCES J(JN),
    PRIMARY KEY (SN, PN, JN)
)
```

Answer (score 2):

First you declare each column and then the reference to another table:

```
 CREATE TABLE SPJ (
    QTY INT,
    SN INTEGER REFERENCES S(SN),
    PN INTEGER REFERENCES P(PN),
    JN INTEGER REFERENCES J(JN),
    PRIMARY KEY (SN, PN, JN)
)
```